# Monogame minimum hardware requirements?

Tags: c#, monogame, .net, mono

What are the minimum hardware / driver requirements for running a Monogame 3.x game, on each of the various Operating Systems?

Comment: That's a good question. Probably not one that any one person can answer. Perhaps it would would work better as a Community Wiki. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts

Comment: Not a bad idea @craftworkgames, if a mod wants to mark it as a Community Wiki - go right ahead.

Comment: As a reference (I'll delete this later), the official supported platforms as of today are: iOS, Android, Mac OS X, Linux Windows 8 Metro, with some others coming soon (WIndows 8 Phone, OUYA, and PlayStation Mobile).

Comment: Don't forget Windows 7, Vista, and I believe XP.

Comment: It's highly likely that the hardware requirements are less than those of the operating system. So, irrelevant. All that's really left are the prerequisite software components, which is what your answers provide.

Comment: @Byte56 not even remotely true. XNA has very high requirements for HiDef, and I know that early 3.x builds of Monogame had really high requirements (OpenGL 3 iirc).

Comment: @Jon You said the minimum hardware requirements. The minimum requirements would not include HiDef.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the upcoming MonoGame SDL2 version;
https://github.com/flibitijibibo/MonoGame

[image]

The SDL2 version is currently not slated to replace the Linux, Mac & GL solutions but when i asked the Dev he replied with "I hope so."
I also asked him about shader versions;

[image]

As MonoGame runs on XP i'd assume that the D3D shader model requirement would be 3.0 (i.e. DirectX 9.0c).
I feel it is also safe to assume then that the current MonoGame ports require GL 2.1 without ARB extensions. Which my laptop must lack.

My laptop for reference is running with an Intel Celeron processor with Mobile Intel® GMA 4500M for graphics (Which i believe has OpenGL 2.0/2.1) and that is currently on Linux(Before I changed it to running Linux I was running windows 7 and the WindowsGL solution would work perfectly fine).

This article on Gamasutra also provides more information on software requirements;

> For Windows desktop, you can use VS 2010 Express or higher, or VS 2012 Express for Desktop or higher on Windows 7 or 8.
>
> For Windows Store, you will need VS 2012 Express for Windows 8 or higher on Windows 8.
>
> For Windows Phone 8, you will need Windows 8 64-bit and the Windows Phone 8 SDK. This will install VS 2012 Express for Windows Phone, and can also work with VS 2012 Professional or higher.
>
> To use the Windows Phone 8 emulator, your PC needs to meet specific hardware requirements; see www.microsoft.com/en-GB/download/details.aspx?id=35471 for details.
>
> For Android and/or iOS, you will need VS 2010 or 2012 Professional or higher and Xamarin Business or higher on Windows 7 or 8.

http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/192209/from_xna_to_monogame.php

Comment: So I have two questions... 1) Is Monogame SDL, in your opinion, ready for production use (Or will it be soon?), and 2) The current Monogame runs on your Laptop or not? Sorry for not understanding that part. Thanks for the reply, too.

Comment: @Jon It is soon to be merged into the official repo. In terms of production quality, flibit is the guy responsible for porting fez to mac & linux (which has just recently been released), he did mention that a few new bugs have been made aware to him but i'm currently using it in my projects and it runs completely fine for me. I would defiantly recommend you using it. As for part two, yep the current monogame runs on my laptop.

Comment: I thought MonoGame SDL2 completely forked off the rails and it's not coming back.  Like they're too far different or something...  At least that's what their website says.

Answer (score 3):

Okay I'll start the wiki.

## Supported Platforms

iOS, Android, Windows (both OpenGL and DirectX), Mac OS X, Linux, Windows 8 Store, Windows Phone 8, PlayStation Mobile, and the OUYA console.

References: http://www.monogame.net/

## Prerequisites

- OpenTK - http://www.opentk.com
- OpenAL - http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/Downloads/oalinst.zip

References: https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/wiki/Tutorials:prerequisites https://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/438421

## Platform Specific Requirements

- iOS - OpenGL ES
- Android - OpenGL ES
- Windows (OpenGL) - OpenGL
- Windows (DirectX) - DirectX
- Mac OS X - OpenGL
- Linux - OpenGL
- Windows 8 Store - DirectX
- Windows Phone 8 - DirectX
- PlayStation Mobile - ?
- OUYA - OpenGL ES

Reference: Project files https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/tree/develop/MonoGame.Framework

## Content Processing

The following are the system requirements for building content for all MonoGame target platforms:

- Windows XP w/SP2, Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8.
- Visual C# 2010 Express or Pro with SP1 installed.
- Windows Phone SDK 7.1 (NOTE: Ensure that you install the Windows Phone SDK 7.1.1 Update shown below.)
- Windows Phone SDK 7.1.1 (**older XNA versions do not work!**)

At this time MonoGame does not include an independent implementation of the XNA content pipeline. We depend on Microsoft's XNA content pipeline implementation and Visual Studio 2010 on Windows to build content for all MonoGame platforms.

Reference: https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/wiki/MonoGame-Content-Processing

---

Comment: Thank you, but the main point of this question was to solve the unanswered question of what the hardware requirements are. No where on Monogame's site, forums, or github do they mention the hardware requirements.

Comment: Note, the site hosting Creative's OpenAL implementation disappeared a few weeks ago, so the OpenAL pre-req link is dead.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the answer either so I provided whatever information I could find to get started with the intent that more people will fill in whatever blanks they can. Maybe we need some specific heading placeholders to show that not all the information is there yet.

Answer (score 3):

I asked the question over on [the Monogame forums](https://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/456254), this is the list that came from that:

> - **Windows Phone 8**: No restrictions. Will run on all Windows Phone 8 devices.
> - **Windows Store**: No restrictions. Same requirements as you you needed to meet to install Windows 8 on that PC.
> - **Windows desktop (OpenGL)**: I think OpenGL 3.0 is the minimum for graphics, plus OpenAL for audio.
> - **Windows desktop (DirectX)**: DirectX 11 installed.
> - **Android**: Android 2.3 minimum.
> - **iOS**: I think iOS 4.0 is the minimum.
> - **Mac OS X**: Should run on all recent and current Mac OS X hardware.
> - **Linux**: OpenGL 3.0 driver support, I think there's some other required packages such as libsdlmixer, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Software:

Windows Vista:
DirectX11 installed
.NET 4.0/4.5 installed

Windows 7:
.NET 4.0/4.5 installed

Windows 8:
No dependancies (DirectX11 + .NET 4.5 already comes with OS)

Hardware:

However, that being said, it really depends on how memory intensive your game is. If it's a game with a lot of models, sprites etc. then you're going to need more RAM. A normal game needs about 2-4 GB of RAM, with a decent processor and a 64-bit OS.

Comment: You got your answer in just before I posted the wiki. If you could integrate your information into the wiki and provide references, that'd be great :)

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question at hand, the question is more about what the hardware / driver requirements are, and what shader model is needed.